# Unable to verify Samsung 870 EVO SSD 500GB

Tags: windows-10, ssd, samsung-ssd, samsung-magician

I have purchased a brand new Samsung 870 EVO SSD 500GB from  local vendor in my city. From the over all looks and performance of the SSD it is working great. But Samsung Magician is unable to verify if the SSD is original or a fake.

I am attaching some images if you can tell me what could be the problem. I have been doing research on this for two days. Tried every possible thing I found on internet but it didn't work. The only thing I got was Samsung Magician accesses this link to verify the SSD `http://wizard.samsungsemi.com`.
And this link is down from I don't know how much time. In the Help docs it says "Ask Your network administrator to register for the following domain", (Link I have mentioned above)

Error on Samsung Magician:

[image: error on Samsung magician]

Note in Samsung Magician Docs

[image: Note in Samsung Magician Docs]

Comment: I am not sure where you got that URL but it’s not valid. [Here](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/magician/?CID=afl-ecomm-rkt-cha-040122-url_Bing+Rebates+on+non-Edge+browsers+and+coupons&utm_source=url_Bing+Rebates+on+non-Edge+browsers+and+coupons&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=1&utm_content=3624890&rktevent=Bing+Rebates+on+non-Edge+browsers+and+coupons_msYS1Nvjv4c-Z5ZLeO8ky8tgigj4BhhXIw&ranMID=47773&ranEAID=msYS1Nvjv4c&ranSiteID=msYS1Nvjv4c-Z5ZLeO8ky8tgigj4BhhXIw) is a working one. Disregard the stuff Bing added to the URL

Comment: @Ramhound
I got that URL from samsung magician help

Comment: It appears that Samsung Magician might not support your fairly older model.

Comment: I have hp pavilion i5 7th generation Laptop and Model number :cc057cl 

@Ramhound

Comment: Which version of Samsung Magician are you using and where did you get it? Also you copied wrongly the link : [https://wizard.samsungsemi.com/](https://wizard.samsungsemi.com/), which seems legit.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSohail - Your SSD is more than 5 year old model. Your title originally said 570. Nevermind

Comment: @harrymc  version of Samsung Magician: 7.1.1,  I have downloaded it from here 
https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/internal-ssd/870evo/

Comment: I find the software rather in [this page](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/). There is also a firmware update here, which might be worth trying.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried to manually update the firmware of SSD but the system does not boot from USB (may be due to unrecognized files)

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch sata port on your motherboard. If you already have more ssd's, you can switch sata connector on the side of the ssd's. My mobo had two controllers, an Intel and a Marvell one. (Asus P8p67 Deluxe) The sata ports on the Marvell controller Were not supported any longer, which gave me same error you experience. Later I found out you have to update controllers in windows-->devices. But Marvell wasn't supported in 10/11 any more. Please try to update chipset mobo/bios, etc. Your SSD is fine, no worries. But if you don't succeed, you will miss trim-option, health status and more important options in magician.